# Creating columns of equal width

Tags: php, arrays, list

So I got a problem that I can't wrap my mind around.

I'm creating a shopping list that is divided into ten categories of various lengths. (All of the items come from a database). I got it to work when using a single column, but I have to divide the list into four columns. The code should decide which categories should go where so that the four columns have the most equal number of items possible.

[This is what the list will look like when the code is working.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEAVn.png)

Out of these ten categories, four of them have a specific category they belong to.

The way I've approached this is to count the total number of items and divide it by four to compute the average number of items per column. I put the four special categories in their respective column and kept track of how many items were now in each column.

Now I still have six columns remaining of various sizes. What is the best approach to put them in the column that would fit best? Since some categories are much larger than others, some columns could potentially have three or four categories.

**UPDATE:** Right after I posted this I came to the realization that I should find the column with the least items and add the largest category to it. This seems like it will work. And it looks like Dave is suggesting the same!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After writing your 4 "main" categories to the columns, make an array that has a total of each column:

```
$columnTotals = array(10,6,12,13)
//example - obviously you'd use count or something to get the totals
```

Then, order your non-special categories in an array by largest to smallest:

```
$subcatTotals = array(18,15,13,12,8,4);
//here, you'll have to get the totals, then use an array sort to order them
//probably want an associative array so you know which total matches which cat.
```

Then, in a loop, add the first(largest) sub-category to the smallest column, and get a new total for that column.

This SHOULD give you the most even columns you can get - at least it has in all the made-up examples I've tried it with.

Comment: I came to this realization a little after posting the question. Thanks a lot!!! I think it's gonna work.

Comment: @Daniel - glad it would have helped, had you not figured it out first :)

Answer (score -1):

Your approach is most ideal in **today's** context. Let me explain...

The ideal thing to do right now is do your little calculation and split the list into the number of rows & columns.

The alternative is a CSS3 approach. i.e., you can create the whole list in ONE column through PHP. And on the CSS side, you can specify the new property "column-count".

But there are issues. This is not yet properly standardised. So you've got to specify the -moze- prefix and -webkit- prefix depending on your browser. But the reason I wouldn't go for this is that IE still does not support this. And it's too early to consider an upgrade by all users even if they did.

Going one step further, you ought to modify your splitting algorithm to take into account the category headings.

Hope this helps :)