# Equal cell width after multiple columns are removed

Tags: html, css

*Update: here is [a follow up question with colspans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9126565/colspan-equal-cell-width-after-multiple-columns-are-removed).*

I have a table with 8 columns. At runtime, **any number of** these  elements are removed.

The remaining columns would have equal width. The problem is when the text inside the  elements has difference width. Because it seems the browser sets the cell widths based on the length of the text inside each cell. OK, this image probably says it better:

[image]

And here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style type="text/css">
table{
    width:600px;
}
table td{
    border:1px solid red;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#FFFFCC;
}
caption{
    color:blue;
    font-size:80%;
}
</style>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <caption>Original table</caption>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
    <tr>
</table>
<table>
    <caption>After some columns are removed</caption>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
    <tr>
</table>
<table>
    <caption>I want these to have the same width</caption>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Two</td>
        <td>Three</td>
        <td>Column number four</td>
        <td>5</td>
    <tr>
</table>
<table>
    <caption>I want these to have the same width, too</caption>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Column number four</td>
        <td>5</td>
    <tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I searched stackoverflow and found the following posts but they are not my answer:

- [Creating columns of equal width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165574/creating-columns-of-equal-width)
- [How do you make a 100% width table with the columns all equal width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055299/how-do-you-make-a-100-width-table-with-the-columns-all-equal-width)

Comment: Couldn't you set the table-layout to fixed and then adjust the cell size by setting each width to the total width divided by the number of cells?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `table-layout:fixed` on the `table` to stop the browser auto resizing the table depending on its contents. Then you will have to give each `TD` a set width. Any `TD`s without a set width will take up the remaining width.

Comment: "Then you will have to give each TD a set width. Any TDs without a set width will take up the remaining width." - so, to make all cells have equal width, the easiest thing to do is to set `table-layout: fixed` on `table` and then not set the width for any `td`s.

Comment: Well, this solved the problem but I have colspans as well. Would you please take a look at my new question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9126565/colspan-equal-cell-width-after-multiple-columns-are-removed

Answer (score 1):

If you use percentages that add up to less than 100% then the web browser usually stretches everything as if it did. If you use percentages that add up to more than 100% then the cells may exceed the set width of the table, depending on browser. As long as they are all the same and they equal less than 100%, then they will divide the space (width of table) equally. If you are not sure how many columns you will have in the future just use 1% for the width. That gives you leeway for up to 100 columns.
However, some testing is required. Not sure if all browsers are behaving this way.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution within jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('table').each(function(){
    var tds = $(this).find("tr").eq(0).find("td").size();
    var percent = 100 / tds;
    $(this).find('td').css('width',percent+'%');
});
});
```

I would recommend adding a class to the tables you want this code to run on to avoid it messing with other tables on the page.

EDIT: Here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rj7UK/

Answer (score 0):

@vaidas was on the right track, but making the columns too small didn't work for me. My solution is to make them too *large*, and in `px` not `%`, like this:

`table td { width: 500px }`

With the latest (Aug'2016) versions of Chrome, Firefox, IE and Edge, it looks like this:[image]