# Colspan + Equal cell width after multiple columns are removed

Tags: html, css, html-table

*PS. I prefer to solve this problem with CSS if possible but if there is no way, I also have access to JQuery (but no other library).*

OK, this is an extension of [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9115878/equal-cell-width-after-multiple-columns-are-removed). When I was asking that question, I tried to make the scenario as simple as possible. But it seems the **colspans** in my table are creating a problem. I have a table with 8 columns. At runtime, any number of these elements are removed. There are a few rows with `colspan="8"` in my table. Using `table-layout:fixed;` I make the cells have equal width. The problem is the cell with `colspan="8"` doesn't resize. This picture shows what I have and what I want:

[image]

And here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style type="text/css">
table{
    width:600px;
    table-layout:fixed;
}
table td{
    border:1px solid red;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#9CF;
}
table td:only-child{
    background-color:#CCFFFF;
}
caption{
    color:blue;
    font-size:80%;
}
</style>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <caption>Original table</caption>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="8">Cell with colspan=8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
    <tr>
</table>
<table>
    <caption>After some columns are removed</caption>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="8">Cell with colspan=8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
    <tr>
</table>
<table>
    <caption>I want these to have the same width</caption>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="8">Cell with colspan=8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Two</td>
        <td>Three</td>
        <td>Column number four</td>
        <td>5</td>
    <tr>
</table>
<table>
    <caption>I want these to have the same width, too</caption>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="8">Cell with colspan=8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Column number four</td>
        <td>5</td>
    <tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How are the columns removed? can you not change the colspan value to match the number of columns when you remove them?

Comment: They are moved using one line of JQuery at runtime according to some data that is received using Ajax. It is possible to use JQuery to set the "colspan" attribute of all the cells that have it, but I prefer a CSS solution if it is possible.

Comment: There is no css equivalent to `colspan="8"`, so you can stop looking. Use Javascript.

Comment: apparently it's possible! See the correct answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT 1: Didn't read the previous linked question.
EDIT 2: I fixed it, it should be working okay now.

I tried to tweak it a bit and I think I got the desired outcome. Now you need to customize the `td` size.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/er7VJ/96/)

Comment: You are relying on the error correction of the browser here. Having different number of columns in table rows is not defined. Different browsers could do different things or this could break in a different scenario. The **only** proper way to do this is to change the `colspan` with JavaScript.

Comment: I don't know what he relied on, but his solution works in FireFox, Opera, Internet Explorer and Chrome.

Comment: It doesn't work! You are just lucky it looks like it in your scenario. Imagine a craftsman banging a screw into a piece of wood with a hammer. That may work and hold for a while, but there's a good chance it will break some time. And would you trust a craftsman doing that?

Comment: It is what we call a hack, Rotora. It is not the optimal solution but it does work when you want to avoid Javascript. I have used this hack for quite a while and it has always worked.

Comment: @Brain: I was under the impression that Alex was removing the columns with JS, so also changing the `colspan` with JS would be fine, but I misread the original question and you are right, using JS would be wrong here. However that just means he should be calculating and changing the `colspan` server-side instead.